# Replace text in MailItem Body

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I've added a ribbon button in the Outlook Explorer, that creates a new email from the selected email when clicked. This works fine using the MailItem.Copy method. But I also need to replace some text in the message body with a different value.

The problem is the email could be a HTML/RichText formatted email and contain text formatting and/or pictures. And simply replacing the text value in the Body property loses all the text formatting and pictures.

So the code below is no good

```
newMailItem.Body = newMailItem.Body.Replace("Old Value", "New Value");
```

And I've also tried loading the HTML and RTF value into a DevExpress RichEditControl and used the RichEditControl.Document.ReplaceAll method to try and replace the text occurrences. But the DevExpress RichEditControl changes/formats the RTF / HTML value differently and causes the message to look wrong when the HTML / RTF is set back in the MailItem.

I've also tried replacing the text by getting a reference to the Word Document (see the code below). But this doesn't work either.

```
Inspector inspector = newMailItem.GetInspector;
if (inspector.IsWordMail())
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument =
        inspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findObject = wordDocument.Application.Selection.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = "old value";
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = "new value";

    object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

So the question is, how can I replace a text value in the MailItem body and ensure the existing text formatting and pictures aren't lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working by displaying the Inspector window, as this seems to resync the MailItem.Body and RTF/HTML properties with the Word Document after preforming the find and replace. But it's slow and flicker'y.

I've pasted the code below.
If anyone can think of a faster and less flicker'y way, please let me know.

```
Inspector inspector = newMailItem.GetInspector;
if (inspector.IsWordMail())
{
    newMailItem.Display();
    wordDocument = inspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = wordDocument.Range(wordDocument.Content.Start, wordDocument.Content.End);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findObject = range.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = "old value";
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = "new value";

    object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTMLBody Instead. It keeps formatting and updates smoothly.

```
    Globals.ThisAddIn.mailItem.HTMLBody = Globals.ThisAddIn.mailItem.HTMLBody.Replace(oldVal, newVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct working code below for this Replace Mail item

```
 public static void Replace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng, string OldValue, object NewValue)
 {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        try
        {
            Find findObject = rng.Find;
            findObject.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Text = OldValue;
            findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Format = true;

            object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, NewValue,
               ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
}
```